# Is there way to replace string in pandas pivot table?

Tags: python, pandas, replace, pivot-table

Is there any way to replace brackets and string within brackets?
I tried this code, it is not displaying error but it is not workind

```
heatmap_data = pd.pivot_table(merged, values='Result', index=['Skill Name'], columns='Employee Name')
heatmap_data = heatmap_data.replace(r"\(.*\)", "", regex=True)
```

Any ideas?

Pivot table
[image: img]

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Comment: Add a example ...

Comment: [img](https://i.imgur.com/d7YeTaM.png)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)? Post code not pics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution not working, because not replace numeric values. You need replace columns and index values:

```
heatmap_data.columns = heatmap_data.columns.str.replace(r"\(.*\)", "")
heatmap_data.index = heatmap_data.index.str.replace(r"\(.*\)", "")
```